# How to Implement Rich snippet in magento Products?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have magento 1.8 and I want to implement Price and Availablity Rich snippet for Magento Products,
on which file I can edit code so my price and Availability snippet will appear in Google?

Comment: Follow this link https://www.byte.nl/blog/magento-rich-snippets-made-easy/

Answer (score 0):

The plugin suggested by @user2434 seems to be pretty good but it is paid/premium but will make your work much easier and faster. However if you want to go all your own free way, you have to hard-code your pages with rich snippet tags. To make it little easy, you can use third party rich snippet code generator tool like http://www.microdatagenerator.com/ and update your individual pages.